# mapscript : adding Label to Layer with persian text

Tags: c#, encoding, persian, mapserver

I am having some issues using Persian text as label. I am using C# mapscript. I am setting the following at runtime:(like button click)

```
 private void addLayer(String layerName)
    {
        if (layer == null)
        {
            //create a layer
            layer = new layerObj(mapInstance);
            layer.type = MS_LAYER_TYPE.MS_LAYER_POINT;
            layer.status = mapscript.MS_ON;
            layer.connectiontype = MS_CONNECTION_TYPE.MS_INLINE;
        }

        // Create a classObj
        OSGeo.MapServer.classObj classobj = new OSGeo.MapServer.classObj(layer);

        //create Label
        labelObj label = new labelObj();
        label.font = "sc";
        label.type = MS_FONT_TYPE.MS_TRUETYPE;
        label.encoding = "utf-8";

        classobj.addLabel(label);

        //add user data
        //create feature
        shapeObj feature = new shapeObj(mapscript.MS_SHAPEFILE_POINT);
        lineObj line = new lineObj();
        pointObj  point = new pointObj(50,50, 0, 0);                
        line.add(point);
        feature.add(line);
        feature.text = "این متن فارسی است :گژپچ";
        layer.addFeature(feature);      

    }
```

But labels are displayed as '?????'.
how can i fix this? Is there any conversion I need to do before setting the text value?

Appreciate any help

Comment: Before setting text value, I tried to convert data from Unicode to uft-8. Some characters are still displayed wrong, either not exact character or a ‘□’ is shown. I used following code:
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode,
           Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("این متن فارسی است: پژگچ"));
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    s.Append(Convert.ToChar(bytes[i]));
feature.text = s.ToString();

Answer (score -1):

Try using different font file: `label.font = "sc";`.
The ‘□’ comes when it can't find the letter in that `.ttf` file.(May be it is not mapped to ttf or mapped to a different Unicode character). You can either go into `.ttf` file and change the font geometry or you can install different font files to get the correct one.

Comment: I tried different font file but still get same error